# Stacked line chart not displaying correctly when Xaxis is time

Tags: javascript, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I try to make a stacked line chart with time as Xaxis.
The problem is that the "stack" part seems to be cumulated at the beginning of each series:

https://codesandbox.io/s/chartjs-idbzk?file=/src/index.js

I'm using chartjs with vue. I use "vue-chartjs": "^3.5.0", "chart.js": "^2.9.3", "vue": "^2.6.11", "vuetify": "^2.2.11"

What did I do wrong?
Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: see i  removed all datapoint and just kept 2 and they are stacked, https://codesandbox.io/s/chartjs-8sj7l?file=/src/index.js

Comment: I gave you answer please mark my answer and bounty as correct

Comment: No, your answer is not correct, you didn't understand the problem because the solution you give doesn't work (see my comments).

Comment: LOL you should have equal data point  for all three lines or stack that is basic principal for stacking chart.

Comment: There are just few charting api where you can have unequal datapoint and they take them in order  like this https://jsfiddle.net/sdfx/hwx9awgn/ but you are using vue and other charting api

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code I see a couple things that I'd suggest you to change:

- Use the `data.labels` attribute to define the xAxes values:

```js
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    labels: [
       new Date("2020-07-01T00:00:00.000Z").toLocaleDateString(),
       ...
       ...
       new Date("2020-07-31T00:00:00.000Z").toLocaleDateString()
```

You should define all the labels from the *min* to *max* value of xAxes.
If you wanna format your Date you can use the native date format methods available (as the one I used as example), or even use a library like moment.js to manage the formatting: [Moment.js Documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/)

Now depending on the output chart you want:

#### Stacked yAxes

- You can remove the following *xAxes* block from `options.scales`:

```js
xAxes: [{
   type: 'time',
   time: {
      unit: 'day'
   },
   distribution: 'series',
   offset: true,
   ticks: {
      major: {
         enabled: true,
         fontStyle: 'bold'
      },
      source: 'data',
      autoSkip: true,
      autoSkipPadding: 75,
      maxRotation: 0,
      sampleSize: 100
   }
}]
```

Then your output should be a proper *yAxes* stacked line chart like this:

[image: Stacked Line Chart]

**Note**: The *xAxes* only shows two values because I only added those on `data.labels`, but as I mentioned earlier you should add all values there.

#### Stacked xAxes

- You can remove the following *yAxes* block from `option.scales`:

```js
yAxes: [{
   stacked: false
}]
```

Then your output should be a chart like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the time you took on your answer. Unfortunately the xAxis has to be 'time' type, because I make operations on it at other places in my code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you did nothing wrong but doubt the current stable version of Chart.js (2.9.3) can handle this case (see this [issue](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/5484)). The stacking is apparently done on values with same index from different datasets, and the `x` value (the time) is ignored.

The good news is that [**Chart.js 3.0.0-alpha.2**](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/releases) seems to render such charts as one would expect. The problem however is that **vue-chartjs** wrapper probably doesn't work together with Chart.js 3.0 yet. Therefore, you'll have to use the Chart.js library directly in your project.

Please have a look at your amended code below.

```js
new Chart('myChart', {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "TEST",
        backgroundColor: "#ffadad",
        data: [
          { x: "2020-07-01T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.4 },
          { x: "2020-07-02T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.4 }
        ]
      },
      {
        label: "Deuxième projet",
        backgroundColor: "#ffd6a5",
        data: [
          { x: "2020-07-03T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.6 },
          { x: "2020-07-04T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.6 },
          { x: "2020-07-05T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.6 },
          { x: "2020-07-06T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.6 },
          { x: "2020-07-07T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.6 },
          { x: "2020-07-08T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.6 },
          { x: "2020-07-09T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.6 },
          { x: "2020-07-10T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.6 },
          { x: "2020-07-11T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.6 },
          { x: "2020-07-12T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.6 },
          { x: "2020-07-13T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.6 },
          { x: "2020-07-14T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.6 },
          { x: "2020-07-15T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.6 },
          { x: "2020-07-16T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.6 },
          { x: "2020-07-17T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.6 },
          { x: "2020-07-18T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.6 },
          { x: "2020-07-19T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.6 },
          { x: "2020-07-20T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.6 },
          { x: "2020-07-21T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.6 },
          { x: "2020-07-22T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.6 },
          { x: "2020-07-23T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.6 },
          { x: "2020-07-24T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.6 },
          { x: "2020-07-25T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.6 },
          { x: "2020-07-26T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.6 },
          { x: "2020-07-27T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.6 },
          { x: "2020-07-28T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.6 },
          { x: "2020-07-29T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.6 },
          { x: "2020-07-30T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.6 }
        ]        
      },
      {
        label: "Premier project",
        backgroundColor: "#fdffb6",
        data: [
          { x: "2020-06-25T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.5 },
          { x: "2020-06-26T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.5 },
          { x: "2020-06-27T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.5 },
          { x: "2020-06-28T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.5 },
          { x: "2020-06-29T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.5 },
          { x: "2020-06-30T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.5 },
          { x: "2020-07-01T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.5 },
          { x: "2020-07-02T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.5 },
          { x: "2020-07-03T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.5 },
          { x: "2020-07-04T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.5 },
          { x: "2020-07-05T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.5 },
          { x: "2020-07-06T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.5 },
          { x: "2020-07-07T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.5 },
          { x: "2020-07-08T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.5 },
          { x: "2020-07-09T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.5 },
          { x: "2020-07-10T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.5 },
          { x: "2020-07-11T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.5 },
          { x: "2020-07-12T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.5 },
          { x: "2020-07-13T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.5 },
          { x: "2020-07-14T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.5 },
          { x: "2020-07-15T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.5 },
          { x: "2020-07-16T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.5 },
          { x: "2020-07-17T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.5 },
          { x: "2020-07-18T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.5 },
          { x: "2020-07-19T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.5 },
          { x: "2020-07-20T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.5 },
          { x: "2020-07-21T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.5 },
          { x: "2020-07-22T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.5 },
          { x: "2020-07-23T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.5 },
          { x: "2020-07-24T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.5 },
          { x: "2020-07-25T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.5 },
          { x: "2020-07-26T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.5 },
          { x: "2020-07-27T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.5 },
          { x: "2020-07-28T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.5 },
          { x: "2020-07-29T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.5 },
          { x: "2020-07-30T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.5 },
          { x: "2020-07-31T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.5 }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    animation: {
      duration: 500
    },    
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    spanGaps: false,
    elements: {
      line: {
        tension: 0.000001
      }
    },
    tooltips: {
      mode: "x",
      intersect: false
    },
    scales: {
      y: {
        stacked: true,
        min: 0
      },
      x: {
        type: "time",
        distribution: "linear",
        time: {
          displayFormats: {
            day: "MMM DD"
          },
          tooltipFormat: "MMM DD"
        },
        ticks: {
          major: {
            enabled: true,
            fontStyle: "bold"
          },
          source: "data",
          autoSkip: true,
          autoSkipPadding: 75,
          maxRotation: 0,
          sampleSize: 100
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.0.0-alpha.2/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-moment@0.1.2/dist/chartjs-adapter-moment.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

> Please consult the Chart.js [3.x Migration Guide](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/getting-started/v3-migration/) in case you consider to migrate your 2.n charts to version 3.0.

Comment: Thank you very much for the time you spent on your answer. However, as explained in my question, I'm using these dependancies: `I'm using chartjs with vue. I use "vue-chartjs": "^3.5.0", "chart.js": "^2.9.3", "vue": "^2.6.11", "vuetify": "^2.2.11".` I didn't see on your link how to migrate using this vue dependancy.

Answer (score 1):

here is the answer
https://codesandbox.io/s/chartjs-8sj7l?file=/src/index.js

see below  you have three datapoints in all three lines.
Then it will be stacked.
Every project must have equal number of rows for x and y variables.
if duexi project has 2 rows and premier project has 3 rows then it cannot be stacked.

```
data: [
          { x: "2020-06-30T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.6 },
          { x: "2020-07-01T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.4 },
          { x: "2020-07-02T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.4 }
        ]
      },
      {
        label: "Deuxième projet",
        backgroundColor: "",
        data: [
          { x: "2020-06-30T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.2 },
          { x: "2020-07-01T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.4 },
          { x: "2020-07-02T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.4 }
        ]
      },
      {
        label: "Premier project",
        backgroundColor: "",
        data: [
          { x: "2020-06-30T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.6 },
          { x: "2020-07-01T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.4 },
          { x: "2020-07-02T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.4 }
        ]
      }
```

You have same labels for multiple days. so I changed setting for chart.
You have unequal datapoints too.
test has two data points others have  multiple.
In order to create a line your all three lines should have equal data points.
you can add zeros and create three lines
your one line is 2 datap oint and shortest and other has 12 datap oints

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but your code doesn't work: look, the lines don't stack well.

Comment: @djcaesar9114 I told you you have duplicate data for same day

Comment: This is not duplicate data, I have several data for the same day, it's normal. Or maybe you could point where the data seems weird for you?

Comment: It is stacked  https://8sj7l.csb.app/  see on left it is 0.2 ,04, 0.6  is th ey axis value. I removed your background color now

Comment: @djcaesar9114  you have just two datapoint for test and others have like 10-12 data point. you should write zero for others so that all thress lines have same data point

Comment: @djcaesar9114 see here stacked line chart https://www.syncfusion.com/vue-ui-components/vue-charts/chart-types/stacked-line-chart

Comment: @djcaesar911  stacked   https://codesandbox.io/s/chartjs-8sj7l?file=/src/index.js

Comment: It still doesn't work, sorry. Try adding `{ x: "2020-06-30T00:00:00.000Z", y: 0.6 }` in the first data of the dataset.

Comment: updated. listen if you want to put a new datapoint you have to add it in all 3.

Comment: No, I don't have to. It seems you didn't understand the problem at all. Thanks anyway.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jinthakur2020/ymxtrwp9/ this is the charting api which can have different number of data points and it still works. LOL WE understand your problem and i saw your reset answer also. that was great answer.